# What's the point of creating and having an opportunity to create a String object out of string pool

Tags: java, string, string-pool

I know that `String` objects are immutable, and I can create `String` object in heap (`String s1 = new String("text1"`) and in string pool (`String s2 = "text2"`). So what's the point of having an opportunity to create a `String` out of string pool? Why Java implicitly doesn't create all `String` object in the string pool? Maybe to prevent the processor from iteration through string pool if chances that some rare string would be there?

Comment: Mostly `new String("text1")` is part of a demonstration or written by someone who doesn't know what they're doing.

Comment: Also, you don't really want every dynamically generated and short-lived String to become internalised. So things like Reader or StringBuilder should be able to create "normal" regular-heap, uncached String instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at it from the perspective of the `new` operator it makes sense.

`new` *always* allocates a new object. That goes for all classes across the board, no exception. It doesn't have any special case behavior for the `String` class, nor any other class. It is completely class agnostic.

I don't see any need for an optimization to be added, either. Writing `new String("literal")` is usually a mistake. Why bother speeding up a mistake?